# Make an HTTP request without a forward slash

Tags: apache, http, url, curl

I came across an odd HTTP request in my Apache access log:

> "GET [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) HTTP/1.0"

Using a browser (Waterfox, Firefox or Chrome, (in that order)) or PuTTY/cURL|Terminal how can I reproduce this HTTP request? Preferably for `localhost` as I can see the logs in real-time.

I did some reading and *apparently* cURL can only make absolute URL requests. I also have not been able to reproduce this with Edit and Resend in the Network panel of Waterfox. This request triggered some minor errors I wish to fix in my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install Telnet.

Then copy and paste the following into a terminal window:

```
telnet localhost 80

GET www.example.com HTTP/1.0
```

Press Enter two times.

This is what it looks like in my access logs:

```
::1 - - [30/Oct/2020:23:37:28 -0700] "GET www.example.com HTTP/1.0" 400 310
```

You can also do this with PHP. Here is a file I created called test.php:

```
<?php
$fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://localhost:80", $errno, $errstr, 30) or die("$errstr ($errno)");
$request = "GET www.example.com HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
$written = 0;
do {
    $bytes = fwrite($fp, substr($request, $written)) or die('fwrite error');
    $written+= $bytes;
}
while ($written!==strlen($request));
fclose($fp) or die('fclose error');
echo 'Request sent successfully';
exit;
```

The above does the same thing it just uses PHP to do it. Create a PHP file with the above text, point your browser to it, it should say "Request sent successfully" and then check your access logs.

Edit:

If you need to use TLS then try the following instead. Again save as test.php and point your browser to this file:

```
$fp = fsockopen("tls://localhost", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30) or die("$errstr ($errno)");
$request = "GET www.example.com HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
$written = 0;
do {
    $bytes = fwrite($fp, substr($request, $written)) or die('fwrite error');
    $written+= $bytes;
}
while ($written!==strlen($request));
while (!feof($fp)) {
    echo fgets($fp, 128);
}
fclose($fp) or die('fclose error');
echo 'Request sent successfully';
exit;
```

Comment: PuTTY: "Connection closed by remote host" for live domain.
I installed Microsoft's version of Telnet and it didn't seem to register with the live domain on port 80 or 443. For localhost the request appeared as so: `::1 - - [31/Oct/2020:02:43:45 -0400] "\xff\xfb\x1f\xff\xfb \xff\xfb\x18\xff\xfb'\xff\xfd\x01\xff\xfb\x03\xff\xfd\x03GET www.example.com" 400 226 "-" "-"`.

Comment: I updated my answer. You'll notice that my access log and yours look different. I don't know what is causing that. Maybe paste it into Notepad first and make sure you're not pasting any funny characters into your terminal window.

Comment: What Telnet client are you using?

Comment: Telnet that comes with Windows 10. It just has to be enabled https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38433.windows-10-enabling-telnet-client.aspx

Comment: I'm just not able to see anything on either Apache log (SSL and non-SSL) on the live domain which I'd rather deal with if there are going to be issues with localhost. Any other ideas? ︀

Comment: I updated my answer with something else you can try using PHP. Replace localhost with your live domain if you have separate logs for each host. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Okay, that worked on localhost, I'm having trouble detecting it with my system on the live domain with TLS: `$fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://www.example.com:443", $errno, $errstr, 30);`. I'm not familiar with `stream_socket_client` and it would really help to be able to have an example where it outputs the HTML/XML code from a basic request. I'm interested in the streaming aspect though not in this instance. I also have never used `while` and `do`, are they necessary for a single request (e.g. is this the server being asynchronous?) or does it have to loop until a response is received?

Comment: fwrite returns the number of bytes sent. do ... while just makes sure that number is the same number as the number of bytes in the message. It's a retry mechanism there as a safeguard. Also the above code won't work on port 443 because it opens a clear connection with no encryption. I might update it again to work with https

Comment: I updated my answer to work with TLS. You will need to replace localhost with your live domain. Try it now.

Comment: Another solution is changing the tcp to tls in $fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://www.example.com:443", $errno, $errstr, 30);

Comment: `[03/Nov/2020:04:44:06 -0500] "GET www.example.com HTTP/1.0" 301 230 "-" "-"` GOT IT! Thank you! Yeah, everything is TLS these days so I'm surprised that wasn't your default go-to. Bytes written from where to where? To a log file of the response from the server? Yes you answered the question technically though I don't understand what you're actually trying to accomplish with the code otherwise? Code is about manipulating text or binary data & then sending it from point A to point B - could you please explain it in that context? How would I store the response from my live server to a variable?

Comment: 1) $bytes is the number of bytes written to the network on each iteration and $written is the number of bytes written to the network in total. 2) Change echo fgets($fp, 128); to $response.= fgets($fp, 128); and $response will contain the whole HTTP response of your live server.

Answer (score 4):

In a terminal it's quite *easy* to perform *any* request.

You can

- use telnet on port 80 `telnet 127.0.0.1 80`. Then you have to write the request (you may need to type fast, and the server may reject you for bad end lines \n instead of \r\n)
- to bypass telnet limitation you can first write your requests with a simple `printf`:

```sh
# regular HTTP query
printf 'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\n\r\n'
# or the 'absolute url' mode
printf 'GET www.example.com HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'
# or even the official absolute uri mode, I think that's the correct one
printf 'GET http://www.example.com/ HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'
```

But `printf` is just the same thing as `echo`, with special charaters handling (like the `\r\n`). So you have to copy the result and paste it to telnet.

I prefer using `netcat` (sometimes called `nc`) to manage the tcp/ip socket connection instead of telnet, and put directly the printf result to the tcp/ip socket with a pipe (if you need https you'll have to use openssl_client instead of netcat). That's:

```
printf 'GET www.example.com HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n' | nc -q 3 127.0.0.1 80
# or
printf 'GET http://www.example.com/ HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n' | nc -q 3 127.0.0.1 80
```

And that's it you have your low tech browser. With the advantage of being able to write any sort of bad query. The aboslute url used in place of the location in the first header is something present in the RFC, to handle compatibility with the very old HTTP 0.9:

```
# HTTP 0.9
printf 'GET www.example.com/foo/bar \r\n' | nc -q 3 127.0.0.1 80
```

And in this request the right VirtualHost to use is the one from the location, not from the Host header:

```sh
# regular HTTP query
printf 'GET http://www.vhost2.com/foo HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.vhost1.com\r\n\r\n' |\
  nc -q 3 127.0.0.1 80
```

That was the base of [James Kettle's Host header attacks back in 2013](https://www.skeletonscribe.net/2013/05/practical-http-host-header-attacks.html). So I recommend you effectively track the *minor events* and fix them. And it's always good to learn how to inject any special url in your server.

You may be able to send crafted requests also with curl, but by definition real browsers and command line browsers tends to avoid sending badly crafted requests.

Tracking real response from HTTP servers from a terminal can also be quite effective when tracking down which server, or proxy is broken when you handle a big chain of such services. Learn how to talk HTTP in a tcp socket, without curl, that's usefull.

Comment: I'll be looking in to this later on this weekend. Looks good from what I've read! I'll accept it after I'm able to confirm. Thank you for taking the time to post!

Comment: `<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand:</p>` is what I get following those directions via Windows 10⇨PuTTY⇨Telnet. That is not my software so I'm pretty sure that I'm not accessing my software in any fashion though the errors that led me to asking this question *did*. I don't see the requests repeated in my access logs for either http or https. Suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

You CAN post crafted requests with curl (to some extent). Curl does not validate method (-X, --request, or CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST). Thus you can use "newline-injection".

Here is example where I send proxy request over HTTP, where I instruct apache acting as reverse proxy, to initiate TLS for me (I use this technique when I need software on some anciet server to be able to communicate with servers that accept only recent versions of TLS).

Note that example uses `bash` variant of echo, to properly insert `CR` and `LF` characters.

```
$ curl -v -X "$(echo -en 'GET https://target.domain/actual/path HTTP/1.1\r\nX-Ignore-Injection:' )" my.apache.proxy.example:8080/ignored/path
* Trying 1.2.3.4:8080...
* Connected to my.apache.proxy.example (1.2.3.4) port 8080 (#0)
> GET https://target.domain/actual/path HTTP/1.1
> X-Ignore-Injection: /ignored/path HTTP/1.1
> Host: my.apache.proxy.example:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.0
> Accept: */*
...
```